# Excel VBA - How to sort by first two letters of cell?

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have two columns I want to sort.  I want it to look exactly like below with Column A first sorted by its first two letters, then by Column B.

```
Column A     -    Column B
AB - Info         3339876
AB - Data         3339877  
AB - Data         3339878 
AC - Info         3339123
AC - Data         3339124
AC - Info         3339125
AD - Info         3339456
AD - Info         3339457
AD - Data         3339458
```

The first two letters of Column A are the MOST important and must be sorted by them first.  The information after the first two letters of Column A is irrelevant and does not matter. It is much more important that the Column B # data to be sorted in ascending order second (after the first two letters of column A)

Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully that clears things up.

Comment: Sorry about that.  There will be a 2nd column getting sorted.  The first column I just want sorted by the first two letters.

Comment: @Josh, Then don't opt to expand all

Comment: It is still not clear why you can't just use the sort feature in Excel. This will sort alphabetically/numerically. Since you dno't care about the 3rd through *n*th letters, it shouldn't matter that they will be accounted for in the sort...

Comment: If it sorts by Column A and uses the entire cell it will not sort in the manner I want it to.  I want it to sort by the first two letter in Column A, and then by numbers that are listed in column B.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Much clearer now. Voting to re-open.

Comment: I think the edited part of my answer should cover this as long as you can add a third column.  You can collapse it if you don't want to look at it.

Comment: Again, why can't you just sort by all of column A, and then all of column B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort normally by highlighting the column and Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>SA</kbd>

---

### Update:

[`'Excel sorts alphanumeric text left to right, character by character'`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322067#MT0), so it may not properly order your numbers if combined into a single cell.  You should create an extra column with just the two letter code that you want to use for sorting by using `=LEFT(A2,2)` and copying all the way down.  Then do a multilayered sort by clicking the sort button, sorting first on the two digit code alphabetically and second on the number column:

[image: example]

Comment: The person wants to satisfy a business need; not right code they don't have to. It seems like the general consensus is that the OP was aware of the extent of the native search functionality. If you can do it automatically, do that. At that point it's up to the asker to clarify that they really do need VBA for reason x, y, or z

Comment: I agree.  It's only constructive afterwards because there was a comment that detailed a complication not present in the original question.  The warning sign here should have been "`Question says it all.`"  If you can ask a question on SO in the number of characters allowed by the title, you're going to get a link to the docs or a refresher course on basic functions almost every single time.

Comment: Creating an extra column inside the data as I already had it structured would have created a collasal headache, so what I did was use Left(string,2) to get the first two characters, deposit them in an adjacent column, sorted, and cleared them out at the end of the script.

Answer (score 1):

the answer above is not excatly correct, it will work until all of the numbers has the same length. but if we have

```
AA 111
AA  99
```

then excel sorts it like this:

```
AA111
AA99
```

(we want the other way around).  you should use the `Left` function as mentioned, but alone, just to create a column with two first letters from the first one. then you have to use the `custom sort`
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sort-data-using-a-custom-list-HA102809333.aspx to sort fisrt by the new column and then by the column with numbers

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells and sort normally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ConradFrix, before you flag, look at the original version of the question which this answer adequately answers.